# SVN repositiry exploring error while uploading review to code collaborator

Tags: svn, code-collaborator

I am trying to upload a review to the code collaborator from SVN repository exploring.
While uploading the review it is throwing an exception

> "An internal error occurred during: "Create new Review ''".
>   javax/net/ssl/TrustManagerFactory. "

Exception stack trace:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/net/ssl/TrustManagerFactory     at
>   com.smartbear.ssl.UserConfirmationSecureProtocolSocketFactory.createTrustManagers(UserConfirmationSecureProtocolSocketFactory.java:73)
>     at
>   com.smartbear.ccollab.client.SOAPClientFactory.getTrustManagers(SOAPClientFactory.java:127)
>     at
>   com.smartbear.ccollab.client.SOAPClientFactory.create(SOAPClientFactory.java:99)
>     at
>   com.smartbear.ccollab.client.commands.Command.validateAndExecute(Command.java:423)
>     at
>   com.smartbear.collaborator.jobs.AddToNewReviewJob.processReview(AddToNewReviewJob.java:46)
>     at
>   com.smartbear.collaborator.jobs.AddToReviewJob.run(AddToReviewJob.java:87)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53) Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Neeba

Comment: This is not internal to SVN, what client and what server are you using? And it seems an SSL error in connecting.

Comment: Using Eclipse SDK
Version: 4.2.2

Collaborator: version 8.1.8100.008

Subversion Client Adapter: 1.8.6

Comment: I copied this eclipse setup from another system where it is working fine.